# Where can I find the latest and best US CD rates online?

Tags: certificate-of-deposit, rates

Where can I find the latest and best US CD rates online?

I'm looking for a clean site that provides updated rates, and can also notify me when CD rates change.

Comment: No notifications, but brokerages that offer bonds will also often sell CDs also. This may be more convenient than having accounts at all the different banks, but may involve a fee.

Answer (score 3):

[Bank Deals Blog](http://www.depositaccounts.com/blog/) is my favorite (now hosted at depositaccounts.com)